# Translating a variable in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Im having trouble doing a translation in my project:

So I have this enum class:

```
enum class Theme(
    val theme: ThemeL,
    val name: String,
    @DrawableRes val image: Int? = null,
){
THEME_1(
        theme = ThemeL.Theme1,
        humanName = "theme1 description",
        image = R.drawable.theme1
    ),
    THEME_2(
        theme = ThemeL.Theme2,
        humanName = "theme2 des",
        image = R.drawable.theme1
    ),
}
```

My question is, I want that "humanName" can be translated to another languages,
in order to do that I created another strings.xml and defined the location I wanted  in android studio, however I cant define here what should I put in "humaname = ..." to achieve so.

my original strings.xml

```
  <string name="theme1">theme one</string>
    <string name="theme2">theme two</string>
```

and the one to be translated in portuguese

```
<string name="theme1">tema um</string>
    <string name="theme2">tema dois</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly translate strings into other languages, you need to create a folder for each language you wish to translate to in RES. For example, name the folder "values-pt". Within this folder, create an XML file called "strings" and place the strings you want to translate inside.

Comment: My problem is that I cant use
 "humanName = stringResource(id = R.string.theme1)"
because "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"

Comment: Please try adding @Composable before your function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using String, you can use String id:

```
enum class Theme(
    val theme: ThemeL,
    @StringRes val humanName: Int,
    @DrawableRes val image: Int? = null,
){
THEME_1(
        theme = ThemeL.Theme1,
        humanName =  R.string.theme1,
        image = R.drawable.theme1
    ),
    THEME_2(
        theme = ThemeL.Theme2,
        humanName =  R.string.theme1,
        image = R.drawable.theme1
    ),
}
```

Then in composable function use String id:

```
@Composable
fun ThemeHuman(theme: Theme) {

  val humanName = stringResource(id = theme.humanName)

}
```

Comment: Thank you man, it worked!

I have another question, right now I only have two langues, justo to begin with, but I want to expand to more languages, and the way I am doing this is a lot of hard code, can you suggest me another approach from the one I am having right now?

Comment: @MatheusQuintas You always use one id for each String, no matter how many language you translated your app. For each String id Android will show the correct language based on user preferences.